# Openseadragon viewer not displaying DZI image

Tags: javascript, deepzoom, openseadragon

We are currently using openseadragon DZI project to create digital pathology viewer for viewing Whole Slide Images. as per the documentation, we did exactly as told. Our viewer does open the navigation tools but does not display the image.

You can check our url:
https://mbracecloud.com/view.php?do=sdf

This is the code we are currently using to call the viewer

```
<script src="openseadragon/openseadragon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
        id: "openseadragon1",
        prefixUrl: "openseadragon/images/",
        tileSources: "https://mbracecloud.com/highsmith.dzi"
    });

</script>
```

How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the network tab of the inspector, you can see that all of the image tiles are 404. For instance:

https://mbracecloud.com/highsmith_files/8/0_0.jpg

It looks like you have highsmith.dzi in the correct location; do you also have the highsmith_files next to it, and is it full of the tiles for that image?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its working now. I went wrong with tiled images concept.

Comment: Its off topic, but since you are here, we like to know how to convert .svs,.tiff files into .dzi extension and  its _files folders through PHP.

Comment: I don't know what .svs is, but if it's a standard image format, hopefully most of the tools work on it. I think everything understands .tiff. At any rate, there are several PHP options here: http://openseadragon.github.io/examples/creating-zooming-images/ In general I use VIPS, which isn't PHP, but I imagine you can execute it from PHP.

Comment: .svs is the format aperio whole slide imaging scanner uses. I did get one lib to convert various wsi extensions to .dzi extension, but it uses imagick dependency which may not really support .svs extension. I would be thankful, if you could really guide me how to use vips in php

Comment: I don't have much experience with PHP, but it looks like this exists: https://github.com/libvips/php-vips Another option might be to use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php to send VIPS command line instructions.

Comment: Yes, you can generate DZI directly from SVS using php-vips. You'll need a linux host, and you may need to build libvips yourself to get openslide support, depending on your platform. Please open an issue on the php-vips github repository if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for answering jcuppit. definitely my bad, but i'm unable to find any example in php-vip that lets create DZI from .svs.